# Scipy SparseEfficiencyWarning when multiplying two matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I am trying to multiply a scipy sparse matrix with a list of values. The code is working as expected but I am getting these two warnings in the `inv` call:

1)SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)

2)SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b ')

The L_plus_I matrix is a type of `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`.

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import inv
from scipy.sparse import identity
import networkx as nx

no_of_nodes = len(g.nodes)

values = list(nx.get_node_attributes(g, 'value').values())

Laplace = nx.laplacian_matrix(g)
Identity = identity(no_of_nodes)
L_plus_I = Laplace + Identity
Inverse = inv(L_plus_I)

solutions = Inverse * values
```

Its somehow obvious that these are generated because `values` is just a list but when I try to make it sparse I get errors on the computations. Also generally speaking how can I improve the running time?

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the `*` line?  The errors look like they are generated in the `inv` call.  A full traceback might help clarify that.  I can't run `nx`, but it might help to know about `L_plus_I`.  There are a number of different `sparse` formats, some better for calculations that others.

Comment: @hpaulj just made a check, you're right the warning is in the `inv` call. Let me edit the question real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a matrix from another question:

```
In [74]: A_sp
Out[74]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 24 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [75]: A_sp.A
Out[75]: 
array([[7, 4, 2, 9, 0],
       [6, 2, 5, 7, 4],
       [6, 6, 4, 3, 1],
       [5, 6, 5, 1, 2],
       [4, 8, 6, 5, 6]])
```

The `inv` with your warnings:

```
In [76]: inv(A_sp)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:318: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:215: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
Out[76]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Looking at the code I see that `inv(A)` is just `spsolve(A,I)

```
In [77]: Identity=sparse.identity(5)
In [79]: Identity
Out[79]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>

In [80]: spsolve(A_sp, Identity)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:318: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:215: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
Out[80]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

convert the `Identity` format:

```
In [81]: spsolve(A_sp, Identity.tocsc())
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py:318: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[81]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Convert `A` as well:

```
In [82]: spsolve(A_sp.tocsc(), Identity.tocsc())
Out[82]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

yea, no warnings :)

```
In [83]: _.A
Out[83]: 
array([[-1.08108108e+00,  4.59459459e-01,  2.97297297e+00,
        -2.40540541e+00, -1.58603289e-16],
       [ 3.04054054e-02, -1.72297297e-01,  1.35135135e-01,
        -9.79729730e-02,  1.25000000e-01],
       [ 1.42567568e+00, -4.12162162e-01, -4.10810811e+00,
         3.62837838e+00, -2.50000000e-01],
       [ 6.21621622e-01, -1.89189189e-01, -1.45945946e+00,
         1.10810811e+00,  8.54017711e-17],
       [-1.26351351e+00,  4.93243243e-01,  3.16216216e+00,
        -2.81756757e+00,  2.50000000e-01]])
```

test against the dense version:

```
In [84]: np.linalg.inv(A_sp.A)
Out[84]: 
array([[-1.08108108e+00,  4.59459459e-01,  2.97297297e+00,
        -2.40540541e+00, -1.58603289e-16],
       [ 3.04054054e-02, -1.72297297e-01,  1.35135135e-01,
        -9.79729730e-02,  1.25000000e-01],
       [ 1.42567568e+00, -4.12162162e-01, -4.10810811e+00,
         3.62837838e+00, -2.50000000e-01],
       [ 6.21621622e-01, -1.89189189e-01, -1.45945946e+00,
         1.10810811e+00,  8.54017711e-17],
       [-1.26351351e+00,  4.93243243e-01,  3.16216216e+00,
        -2.81756757e+00,  2.50000000e-01]])
```

Actually `inv` uses `I = _ident_like(A)`, so this is enough:

```
In [85]: inv(A_sp.tocsc())
Out[85]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

Comment: A nice explanation, also the `np.linalg.inv` seems to compute much faster. I made some modifications also to my script and also post it as an answer for anyone stumbling here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above question I found this way that also computes faster.

```
Inverse = np.linalg.inv(L_plus_I.todense())

solutions = Inverse.dot(values)
```